# How to disable click item in array of obects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to disable a item that is part of an array of objects for the user.

So I have this api data:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "name": "bulldog",
    "description": "bulldog",
    "legislation": "",
    "review": "",
    "eaza": "",
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/media/photos/categories/bulldogs.png",
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Olde English Bulldogge",
            "description": "Olde English Bulldogge",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/media/photos/animals/Olde_English_Bulldogge.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "French bulldog",
            "description": "French bulldog",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/media/photos/animals/French_bulldog.png"
        }
    ],
    "subcategories": [],
    "category": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/13/"
}
```

And a user can click on the id with 17 and then the user sees to more items in this case: 6 and 7. But I try to disable the click function on these two items: 6 and 7.

So I have this component:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
            if (data.animals.length > 0) {
                setSubCategoryList(data.animals);
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setSubCategoryList(data.subcategories);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }, [route]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {isLoading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <CategoryList
                data={subCatgoryList}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    console.log(item);
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}
                            disabled={
                                isLoading || (item?.subcategories?.length === 0 && item?.animals?.length === 0)
                            }>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

But of course the items with id 6 and 7 don't have both the propertie animals and subcategories.

Question: how to disbable the items in the array of animals?

Comment: Not sure if i understood your problem but I guess while rendering you can check if current item has animals property. If not you can disable click.

Comment: @CodeThing I tried like: disabled={isLoading || !Object.hasOwnProperty(item.animals, "subcategories")}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
disabled={isLoading || (!item.hasOwnProperty('animals') && !item.hasOwnProperty('subcategories'))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, here we first check if the item has `subcategories` and then check for the length. Same with the `animals`.

Currently it will return `false` if the item has either a `subcategories` or `animals` props. If you want both required, you can change the `||` to a `&&`.

```js
const hasSub =
  (item.subcategories && item.subcategories.length === 0) ||
  (item.animals && item.animals.length === 0);

renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}
      disabled={isLoading || hasSub}
    >
      ...
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}}
```

Comment: Hi Ruben. Thank you for your help. But I tried that and also with  &&. But apparantly that doesn;t work. What CodThing posted works.